# Bash : Filter file by last word

Tags: bash, awk, uniq

I have a log file which looks like this :

```
Sun Oct 14 03:38:28 2018 [pid 5922] command: Client "0.0.0.0", "USER macly"
Sun Oct 14 03:38:58 2018 [pid 5940] command: Client "0.0.0.0", "USER tredred"
Sun Oct 14 03:40:41 2018 [pid 6870] command: Client "0.0.0.0", "USER sweet"
Sun Oct 14 03:40:47 2018 [pid 7037] command: Client "0.0.0.0", "USER sweet"
```

Iam trying to edit the file such that it keeps the 1st occurance of a 'User' and deletes the rest. So basically the above block will look like :

```
Sun Oct 14 03:38:28 2018 [pid 5922] command: Client "0.0.0.0", "USER macly"
    Sun Oct 14 03:38:58 2018 [pid 5940] command: Client "0.0.0.0", "USER tredred"
    Sun Oct 14 03:40:41 2018 [pid 6870] command: Client "0.0.0.0", "USER sweet"
```

The lines arent really 'unique' since the timestamp differs. The thought I could use `awk` and then do a `uniq` :
`awk '{print $NF}' /home/user_logs | uniq`

but that just me the last word of each line and not the whole line. What do i need to add to my command to keep the whole line ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need `uniq`

```
$ awk -F, '!a[$NF]++' file

Sun Oct 14 03:38:28 2018 [pid 5922] command: Client "0.0.0.0", "USER macly"
Sun Oct 14 03:38:58 2018 [pid 5940] command: Client "0.0.0.0", "USER tredred"
Sun Oct 14 03:40:41 2018 [pid 6870] command: Client "0.0.0.0", "USER sweet"
```

**Explanation**

`a[$NF]++` post counts occurrences of the last field values, obviously will be zero for the first and non-zero for the subsequent values. negation (`!`) of this value (treated as logical, 0~false; 1~true) is only `true` for the first instance of a value.  Default action is `{print $0}`, so not written explicitly.

This is the standard `awk` idiom to print unique values which doesn't require sorting the file.

Comment: wow. umm can you explain what exactly is going in in the command

Answer (score 0):

̲I̲f̲  the data is fixed width, you can use `uniq`

```
$ uniq -s 63 file
Sun Oct 14 03:38:28 2018 [pid 5922] command: Client "0.0.0.0", "USER macly"
Sun Oct 14 03:38:58 2018 [pid 5940] command: Client "0.0.0.0", "USER tredred"
Sun Oct 14 03:40:41 2018 [pid 6870] command: Client "0.0.0.0", "USER sweet"
└──────────────────────────────63─────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: you need to sort it first!

Comment: @karakfa True .

Comment: ... so it'd be something like: `sort -k1.64 file | uniq -s 63`